# Cakephp: generic validation rules in AppModel?

Tags: validation, cakephp

I'm wondering what's the "best" approach to validate fields generically. In my application several tables have date values that are always entered using a date picker widget. I don't want to repeat the validation code, so I would like to do something like filling the $validate array in the AppModel. But it gets overwritten in the concrete model class. The best I found so far is the paragraph "Dynamically change validation rules" in the cake book, and apply that logic to the AppModel somehow, but it looks a bit hacky and un-caky. Does anyone have a hint?
(If you have questions, please ask.)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just name them differently - unique so to speak:

```
public function validateDateTime() {}
```

etc. This way your custom rules don't verwrite the core rules and vica versa.

Answer (score 0):

I had some validation rules that I wanted to put in 3 models, to not repeat the same code, here what I did

in AppModel.php, define some var with those rules that should be in multiple models.

```
public $validationRules = arra(
  // rules here
);
```

and add them for necessary models in AppModel's constructor

```
public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
    parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);

    /**
     * add validation
    */
    if (in_array($this->alias, array('MyModel1', 'MyModel2', 'MyModel3')) ) {
        $this->validate = array_merge($this->validate, $this->validationRules);
    }
}
```

if there are some custom validation functions, those can be moved to AppModel.php as well.